# "Encrypt the whole drive" option disabled on VeraCrypt

Tags: veracrypt

I want to encrypt my whole drive with VeraCrypt but the option is disabled. I have another PC where it's not disabled. Both are running Windows 10. What should I do? Oh and in addition, does encrypting the whole drive also encrypt other non-windows partitions? I have a linux partition as well.

[image: Screenshot]

Edit: Add screenshot of disk management, the windows partitions are the ones labeled C and D. The unallocated 60GB partition will be for linux. Can I encrypt everything on the hard drive, including the linux partitions? Or at least everything under windows.

[image: disk management]

Comment: Please show us a screenshot from that system's Disk Management utility, with the partition you are trying to encrypt highlighted.

Comment: I'm going to assume that the edit under a different username is you.  You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection it must be done under the original user account, which isn't possible since this was migrated here.  This will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://$SITEURL$/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Comment: Please verify the edit and roll it back if necessary if you were not its author.

Comment: Oops, yes, that edit was me, didn't realize I was logged in under a different account.

Comment: I think the answer for the reason for this with this software is contained within this post: https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Issues%20and%20Limitations. Tag me back with an `@`  symbol followed by my username (e.g. @Sunday) so I get the notification and let me know if you see anything helpful in that.

Comment: It looks like you use GPT. I've seen various reports that VeraCrypt doesn't support GPT, only MBR for full disk encryption. I cannot find the *current* status nor any official information (that's why it's a comment, not an answer). This another PC you mentioned may use MBR, check this out.

Comment: Yes, that's actually the most likely explanation, the other PC uses MBR. https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/discussions/547604 I'm not sure what this means though. I'll try some things, and if it works, I'll post an answer. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, @KamilMaciorowski